# How can I resolve the faulting error in Apache

Tags: apache

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.48.0, time stamp: 0x60a37f00
Faulting module name: opencv_videoio_ffmpeg460_64.dll, version: 2022.5.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x0000000000f7fd52
Faulting process id: 0x102d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d913a882251b82
Faulting application path: C:\AI_People_Counter\Software_Files\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg460_64.dll
Report Id: 63bbc67f-ae93-4b02-83d9-f9541a09f63b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please start by taking the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that's related to programming ([help/on-topic]) to be answerable and on-topic.

Comment: Are you knowingly using a Python video encoder library when the crash happens?